# how to crop-area with different height/width size? with ngImgCrop

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to crop not same height/width crop-area can I use rectangle crop-area.

```
<div>Select an image file: <input type="file" id="fileInput" /></div>
    <div class="cropArea">
    <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage" area-type="square" area-min-size="20" result-image-size="150"></img-crop>
     </div>
<div>Cropped Image:</div>
<div><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" /></div>
```

I need set height/width like area-min-size="{100, 150}" result-image-size="{100, 150}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see - it is not possible, as it involves a more complex manipulation of the selector area (e.g., it will need to resize in two dimensions independently).

There is an alternative however. Though it might be not as much of an eye candy as ngImgCrop, but it achieves what you need. [ http://grab.by/Cbpq ]

It is called: [angular-image-crop](https://github.com/andyshora/angular-image-crop).

Here is a [JSBin sample](http://jsbin.com/fovovu/1/edit?html,output).

You may need to play around with the following parameters `data-width="", data-height="", dat-shape="square"` before the result is satisfying:

```
<image-crop
     data-width="500"
     data-height="300"
     data-shape="square"
     data-step="imageCropStep"
     data-result="imageCropResult"
     ng-show="showImageCropper"
   ></image-crop>
```

Comment: is there a way to get rid of zoom button ?

Answer (score 1):

@Bilegsaikhan, I found a modified version of ngImgCrop which supports rectangular crop as well as a fixed aspect ratio. [Here I created a JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/melnikovkolya/a2ew3yhf/2/).

One could fiddle with the `result-image-size="400"` parameter to tailor the intermediate/resulting image size (this parameter defines the canvas size of an intermediate step). For the size of the final `img`, normal `height` and `width` of the image node can be changed.

Enjoy :)

Comment: tnx for reply i used angular-image-crop that was not bad works for me.

Comment: In this example the aspect ratio is not fixed. How do you make it ti be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this library https://github.com/vogloblinsky/ngImgCropExtended ? It probably extends the feature from ngImgCrop and supports area type like circle, square and rectangle